# Fourier serier with complex integral

Tags: fourier-series, complex-integration

I have a problem with a long calculus of Fourier series coefficient.

The integral is $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^4 cos{nx} dx$.

How can resolve quickly with $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^4 e^{-inx} dx$ instead of integral by parts??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int_a^b x^4\cos(nx)dx=\text{Re}\int_a^b x^4e^{-inx}dx=\text{Re}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial n^4}\int_a^b e^{-inx}dx$$
and
$$\int^\pi_{-\pi}e^{-inx}dx=\frac{e^{-\pi ni}-e^{\pi ni}}{-ni}=\frac2n \sin(n\pi)$$

Comment: Thank you very much $Szeto$. Do you have some link about theory of that?

Comment: @Simo dealing with e^x is often much easier than cos x or sin x, so whenever we have a real integral involving cos x and sin x, one may try make it complex and take the real/imaginary part only. Note that this trick works only when the trig function appears in the numerator alone. The second trick I used is called the Feynman’s trick. Search it on google and you will get tons of related information.

Comment: Thank you very much. I lost a lot of time during exam integrating by parts. Now I know another method.Regards